# How To replace leading zero with spaces in linux?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

i have text like this

```
Jan 28\|Jan 29\|Jan 30\|Jan 31\|Feb 01\|Feb 02\|Feb 03\|Feb 04
```

i want to the result like this

```
Jan 28\|Jan 29\|Jan 30\|Jan 31\|Feb  1\|Feb  2\|Feb  3\|Feb  4
```

i have been searching all over and get no result, please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `gawk` you can use `gensub`:

```
awk '{print gensub(/ 0([0-9])/,"  \\1", "g")}' file
Jan 28\|Jan 29\|Jan 30\|Jan 31\|Feb  1\|Feb  2\|Feb  3\|Feb  4
```

Or same pattern with `sed`:

```
sed  's/ 0\([0-9]\)/  \1/g' file
Jan 28\|Jan 29\|Jan 30\|Jan 31\|Feb  1\|Feb  2\|Feb  3\|Feb  4
```

Comment: With `gensub` you can use print. So `awk '{print gensub(/ 0([0-9])/,"  \\1", "g")}' file` would work just fine.

Comment: Second digit `[0-9]` is useless in pattern because numbers after `10` won't start with `0`.

Comment: It may not be *numerically* sensible but it is pattern sensible. It qualifies that we are replacing `[ ](0)(\d)` vs `[ ](0)(\D)`. And it has 0 cost to do that...

Comment: You made the choice of a minimalist pattern and IMO you don't need to add `[0-9]` after `0` in this context, it doesn't make your pattern much more secure. The sample code can be the header of a csv file with a lot of `0[0-9]` in it.

Answer (score 2):

A minimal pattern to simply replace space followed by `0` with two spaces(because 2 digits days won't have a leading `0`):

```
sed 's/ 0/  /g' file
```

Add the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/ 0/  /g' file
```

If you want to be more restrictive, with backreference you can search and replace months followed by one space and `0` with month and space without the `0`:

```
sed 's/\(|[A-Za-z]\{3\} \)0/\1 /g'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Jan 28\|Jan 29\|Jan 30\|Jan 31\|Feb 01\|Feb 02\|Feb 03\|Feb 04"|\
> awk '{gsub(/ 0/,"  ")}1'

Jan 28\|Jan 29\|Jan 30\|Jan 31\|Feb  1\|Feb  2\|Feb  3\|Feb  4
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\b[0-9]\b/0&/g' file
```

Prefix a singleton digit with a zero.